# Respond to GPIO in fastest way possible

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, c

I'm trying to respond to a trigger from a ~1MHz clock and I'm having trouble doing this in the time required (under 400ns). I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3b+ and I've seen benchmarks of 50Mhz+ for toggling the pins so I would have thought this was possible. I've written my code in C compiled with the `-O3` flag and the fastest response I can achieve is around 670ns which is far too slow. My code is roughly:

```c
*gpclr = 0xffffa7; // Clear outputs
*gpfsel0 = 0xc000; // Set input pins
*gpfsel1 = 0x0;
*gpfsel2 = 0x0;

// *** Start of measure here
while (!(*gplvl & pi_rd)) ; // Wait for signal
const u_int32_t data = *gplvl; // Read all pins
const u_int16_t address = (data >> PI_DATA) & 0xffff; // Get address
// Set outputs
*gpfsel0 = 0x900c049;
*gpfsel1 = 0x9249249;
*gpfsel2 = 0x0000249;
*gpset = pi_wr; // Set write signal

// *** 660-900ns to here

const u_int8_t byte_to_send = address & 0xff; // Create a data byte
*gpset = (byte_to_send << PI_DATA); // Set GPIO output
*gpclr = pi_wr; // Clear write signal
```

I know for certain this has been done with a Pi3 bare metal so I'm wondering if there is a reason why it is so slow under Raspbian. Is it possible and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what to say.  You are using a busy wait.  That is the fastest way to respond to the event.

Comment: @joan Yes, that was what I thought. It just seems slower than I expected.

Comment: you are not going to get those kinds of responses (certainly not reliably) without the use of a real time os.

Comment: Either something isn't right with my setup or GPIO input benchmarks are wrong. I have tried bare metal and inspected the assembly output and the busy loop is as tight as possible (3 instructions) and yet from receiving the input to setting the pin high in the next instruction it is taking 390ns. This doesn't seem to match a 10MHz sample rate or 40+MHz toggle rate